# Why is tbody's width equal to the width of the first header in this set up?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to have the table show overflow-y as a scroll. I was using [this fiddle as an example](http://jsfiddle.net/dandv/JPGEk/). I already tried to change the `th` to `td` to no avail and I'd prefer to keep the `th` for the style if possible. What is wrong with my set up that makes it so that my entire `<tbody>` gets placed in the same column as the first header?

My current example (the one with issues) can be seen at:
https://jsfiddle.net/vLkgjxwq/

Comment: To really understand what's going on you need to get to grips with the [anonymous table objects](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) that are created when you apply `display:block` to a tbody element. But the sad truth is there is no way to have independent scrolling row groups of a table, whilst preserving the integrity of the single table at the CSS level.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation that you're modeling your code after will only work for one column. You can remove `display:block` to fix your column layout, but then your `overflow-y: scroll` rule won't work.

Sadly, the only way I know to achieve the desired result would be with nested tables (yuck)

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <td>header</td>
    <td>header</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class='eventbody'>
                <tr><td>Testing</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Testing</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Testing</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Testing</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Testing</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Testing</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Testing</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table class='eventbody'>
                <tr><td>Testing</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Testing</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Testing</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Testing</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Testing</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Testing</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Testing</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.eventbody {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vLkgjxwq/2/)**

Comment: I just wrapped the entire table in a div and set that overflow. Not the greatest solution, but less pain